# как обойти null

Tags: javascript, циклы, while

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть проблема в цикле нужно получить данные в определенном виде USD , но нужно сделать юзеру скочуху и что бы он мог и так написать - usd для этого использую .toUpperCase().
Если без .toUpperCase() то в while  достаточно и такого условия(!userData[currencySelection]) , но это все не то (
Проблема заключается. в том что при отмене все крашится и цикл не работает

```
   let currencySelection = '';
       do {
        currencySelection = prompt(`Введите название валюты в формате :USD, EUR, UAH, BIF, AOA`).toUpperCase();
        .toUpperCase();
         
       } while (!currencySelection && !userData[currencySelection]);
      
       console.log(`Баланс составляет: ${userData[currencySelection]} ${currencySelection}.`)
```

Comment: `(prompt('....') || '').toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 0):

```
let currencySelection = ''; userData = {USD:100};
   do {
    currencySelection = (prompt(`Введите название валюты в формате :USD, EUR, UAH, BIF, AOA`)||'').toUpperCase();
     
   } while (!currencySelection && !userData[currencySelection]);
  
   console.log(`Баланс составляет: ${userData[currencySelection]} ${currencySelection}.`)
```

Comment: та нет userData это объект с которого идет сравнение , его изменять или трогать нельзя

Comment: Обрати внимание, что userData только как пример представлен. Решение на 3й строчке.

Answer (score 0):

```
let currencySelection = '';
        do {
            currencySelection = prompt(`Введите название валюты в формате :USD, EUR, UAH, BIF, AOA`);
    
            if (currencySelection) {
                currencySelection = currencySelection.toUpperCase();
            }
             
           } while (!currencySelection || !userData[currencySelection]);
          
           console.log(`Баланс составляет: ${userData[currencySelection]} ${currencySelection}.`)
```